# Extract value from result Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, grep, nagios

I have a Linux command line to display a certain result. From the result, I would like to grep it or use awk to pull out a specific value. This is the result of the command line:

```
OK 0 seconds over max, 0 active processes, next process in the future|'overmax'=0s;300;600 'active'=0 'nextoldest'=-1153s
```

All I want is to display on the value after 'active'=? which would be in this instance 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this grep line:

```
grep -Po "'active'=\K\S*"
```

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick. Just so I understand this, can you explain the regEx bit

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover `-P PCRE`, `-o only`, `\S*` all non-empty chars after `'active'=` the `\K` does the positive look behind, but dynamic length.

Answer (score 2):

You could use egrep like this :

```
egrep -o "'active'=[^\ ]+"
```

Example :

```
[ ~]$ str="OK 0 seconds over max, 0 active processes, next process in the future|'overmax'=0s;300;600 'active'=0 'nextoldest'=-1153s"
[ ~]$ echo $str|egrep -o "'active'=[^\ ]+"
'active'=0
[ ~]$
```

If you're sure that the right value is numeric, you can further restrict the pattern like this :

```
egrep -o "'active'=[0-9]+"
```

You could use sed too :

```
[ ~]$ echo $str|sed "s/.*\('active'=[^\ ]*\).*/\1/g"
'active'=0
```

And if you want to get only the right value :

```
[ ~]$ echo $str|sed "s/.*'active'=\([^\ ]*\).*/\1/g"
0
```

You could use awk too but I think that is not the better solution in this case. But just for fun :

```
[ ~]$ echo $str|awk -F " " '{for (i=1; i <= NF; i++){if($i ~ ".?active.?="){print $i}}}'
'active'=0
```

N.B : egrep is equivalent to "-E" option of grep.

Answer (score 1):

Another `gnu awk`

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*active.=(.*) .*/,"\\1","g")}' file
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ match($0,/'active'=(.*) /,a); print a[1]}' file
```